# Custom Object Approval Process Omni-Channel Routing Configuration

Tags: approval-process, omnichannel

I have a Custom Object + Approval Process assigned to a Queue- that I would like to be assigned as a Work-Item via Omni-Channel router. I have configured the necessary configurations (I think), however, when I log in as one of my Queue members and set their Presence Status to an "Available" state, they do not receive a new "Work Item".

*Maybe I'm just misunderstanding Approval Process relationships to Work Items in Omni-Channel Routing on a Queue: **I assume that if an agent is a member of a Queue, and that Queue is assigned as an Approver in an Approval Process, then when a new record is assigned to that queue, the member is notified that that approval is a work item for them by Omni-Channel Router?***

Here is my setup to see where I am missing something:

New Custom Object = `Credit_Request__c`, with a custom field `Type__c` with picklist value `Wireless` and `Non-Wireless`.

I have created a Queue for these Custom Objects:
[image: Queue Setup]

I have an `Approval Process` for `Credit_Request__c`:

[image: CR Approval Process]

I have added a trigger to submit the record for Approval as soon as it's inserted:

```
trigger CreditRequestTrigger on Credit_Request__c (after insert) {

 List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> requestList = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();
    List<Approval.ProcessResult> resultList = new List<Approval.ProcessResult>();
    try{
        for(Credit_Request__c creditRequest: Trigger.new){
                            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                req.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
                req.setObjectId(creditRequest.id);
                requestList.add(req);
        }
        resultList = Approval.process(requestList);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('error when submitting for approval: ' + e);
        for(Approval.ProcessResult result : resultList){
            if(result.getErrors().size() > 0){
               // creditRequestMap.get(result.getEntityId()).addError('There was a problem submitting for approval');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have created a `Service Channel` associated with the Custom Object:
[image: Service Channel]

Routing Configuration:

[image: routing configuration]

And Presence Status- which I have made available to the profile of my Queue Member:

[image: presense status]

And those presence statuses are associated with the appropriate channel:

[image: presence status channel]

I then create a record with my user (Manually inserting from Dev. Console), and I don't see any errors with the Approval Process trigger running.

[image: approval process invoked]

However when I log in as a Queue Member and set my presence status as "Available" I do NOT see any work items?

[image: console omni-channel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user with whom I was logged in ***did not have a Service Cloud License***.

I opened their User record and made sure the 'Service Cloud User' checkbox was checked.

I then logged as the user and set my status to 'Available' at which point I immediately received my pending approval requests.